# How do I link relative to a Pylons application root?

Tags: python, pylons, mako

In Pylons I have a mako template linking to `/static/resource.css`. How do I automatically link to `/pylons/static/resource.css` when I decide to map the application to a subdirectory on my web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your static file links to be relative to your app root, wrap them like this in your templates (assuming Mako and Pylons 0.9.7):

```
${url('/static/resource.css')}
```

The root path of your app will be prepended. No need to define specific routes for each file.

Answer (score 1):

What you want are [static routes](http://routes.groovie.org/manual.html#static-named-routes):

```
map.connect('resource', '/static/resource.css', _static=True)
```